# Is [CallerMemberName] slow compared to alternatives when implementing INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, callermembername

There are good articles that suggest [different ways for implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://blog.amusedia.com/2013/06/inotifypropertychanged-implementation.html).

Consider the following basic implementation:

```
class BasicClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int sampleIntField;

    public int SampleIntProperty
    {
        get { return sampleIntField; }
        set
        {
            if (value != sampleIntField)
            {
                sampleIntField = value;
                FirePropertyChanged("SampleIntProperty"); // ouch ! magic string here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to replace it with this one:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class BetterClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    // Check the attribute in the following line :
    private void FirePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int sampleIntField;

    public int SampleIntProperty
    {
        get { return sampleIntField; }
        set
        {
            if (value != sampleIntField)
            {
                sampleIntField = value;
                // no "magic string" in the following line :
                FirePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But sometimes I read that the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute has poor performances compared to alternatives. Is that true and why? Does it use reflection?

Answer (score 227, accepted):

No, **the use of `[CallerMemberName]` is not slower** than the upper basic implementation.

This is because, according to [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh534540(v=vs.110).aspx),

> Caller Info values are emitted as literals into the Intermediate
>   Language (IL) at compile time

We can check that with any IL disassembler (like [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/)) : the code for the "SET" operation of the property is compiled exactly the same way :
[image: Decompiled property with CallerMemberName]

So no use of Reflection here.

(sample compiled with VS2013)