# Is it possible to implement Property Changed as Attribute?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have found an implementation of Propperty Changed Event, where i can Call Property changed without the Name of the Property in the web. And then i have build a Extension Method with it wich is here

```
public static void OnPropertyChanged(this INotifyPropertyChanged iNotifyPropertyChanged, string    propertyName = null)
{
    if (propertyName == null)
        propertyName = new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name.Replace("set_", "");
    FieldInfo field = iNotifyPropertyChanged.GetType().GetField("PropertyChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    if (field == (FieldInfo) null)
        return;
    object obj = field.GetValue((object) iNotifyPropertyChanged);
    if (obj == null)
        return;
    obj.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke").Invoke(obj, new object[2]
    {
        (object) iNotifyPropertyChanged,
        (object) new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)
    });
}
```

So i can call Property changed like this:

```
private bool _foo;
public bool Foo
{
    get { _foo; }
    private set
    {
        _foo = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

But I thought, it would be nicer if i don't have to implement the getter and setter of a Property when i use Property changed.

Does anyone now how to implement the OnPropertyChanged Method as Attribute, maybe with AOP?

So that Auto-Property can be used for Property Changed like this:

```
[OnPropertyChanged]
public bool Foo {set;get;}
```

Comment: Another thing, rather than doing the expensive StackFrame unwinding use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580623/inotifypropertychanged-is-callermembername-slow-compared-to-alternatives

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody), and the [PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) add-in. It will modify the IL after compilation to add the code to raise the `PropertyChanged` event for your properties. It's similar to PostSharp, mentioned in Lasse's answer, but it's free and open-source.

Answer (score 4):

You will need some kind of AOP system to do this.

Either something where you wrap or inherit from your class, and dynamically generate the necessary plumbing in the wrapper/descendant to handle this, or some system like [Postsharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) that rewrites your code after compilation.

There is nothing built into .NET to handle this.