# INotifyChangedProperty dynamic implementation

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, metaprogramming

In most tuts they say to write method like this:

```
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

and call it such as `OnPropertyChanged("PropName");`. But this seems to be very static and unable to refactor automatically. Is there a way to do this more dynamically? I considered using `System.Diagnostic.StackTrace` class to get the name of property, but it looks ugly and not much efficiently, and moreover I can't access it in for instance Windows Phone 8 app (why!?).

Comment: What do you mean when you say "a static implementation"?

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("PropName");` - you have to provide string known in compile-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [[CallerMemberName]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are using .NET Framework 4.5

so your code  will be :

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class BetterClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    // Check the attribute in the following line :
    private void FirePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int sampleIntField;

    public int SampleIntProperty
    {
        get { return sampleIntField; }
        set
        {
            if (value != sampleIntField)
            {
                sampleIntField = value;
                // no "magic string" in the following line :
                FirePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

as described in the question [INotifyPropertyChanged : is [CallerMemberName] slow compared to alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580623/inotifypropertychanged-is-callermembername-slow-compared-to-alternatives)

Answer (score 0):

[Caliburn.micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/configuration) has a `PropertyChangeBase` that allows you to use lambdas. You can inherit from it and call the base method. For a property `Name` you can do this:

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Name);
```

With C# 6.0 you can implement your own base class and use the `nameof` operator, which will help with refactoring:

```
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
```

Comment: [SharpObservation](https://sharpobservation.codeplex.com/) and [MVVM Light Toolkit](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) have these base-classes as well :)