# Bind ObservableCollection to DataGrid with auto refresh

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'am trying to bind a ObservableCollection list to a datagrid.

The Values in the list change every 100ms. 
I want that the grid automatically refreshs if a value changed.

Here is a little demo project to make it work. But without the refresh UI button, nothing works right.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<DemoItem> ItemList = new ObservableCollection<DemoItem>(); 

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DemoItem di1 = new DemoItem();
        di1.Name = "Spieler 1";
        di1.Zufallszahl = 0;
        di1.Alter = 21;

        DemoItem di2 = new DemoItem();
        di2.Name = "Spieler 2";
        di2.Zufallszahl = 0;
        di2.Alter = 15;

        ItemList.Add(di1);
        ItemList.Add(di2);

        DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);
        dt.Tick += Dt_Tick;
        dt.Start();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DemoItem> ObservableDemoItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ItemList;
        }
    }

    private void Dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();

        ItemList[0].Zufallszahl = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
        ItemList[1].Zufallszahl = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="359.428" Width="539.141">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="10,10,0,0" SelectionMode="Extended" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Height="199" Width="497" CanUserAddRows="False" 
        CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding ObservableDemoItem}" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Alter" Binding="{Binding Alter}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Aktiv" Binding="{Binding Zufallszahl}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Update UI" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Margin="55,245,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="425" Height="61" Click="button1_Click"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

What do I need to change, to make it work?

Comment: DemoItem-Class has to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) Interface, thats all. Read about it here and on MSDN to understand whats happening. In short: Whenever a property is set you've to call the `PropertyChanged`-Event which is handled by your Collection. And please do me a favor and dont write mix-code with german and english

Comment: @Nitro.de is correct, DemoItem needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Here's an answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22580623/424129

Comment: `ObservableCollection` notifies only if an element has been added or removed, not if an existing element has been changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` notifies the UI about changes (raises a `CollectionChanged` event) only if an element has been added or removed, not if an existing element has been changed.

To track changes in collection's elements, like `Nitro.de` and `Ed Plunkett` suggested, the element's class should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
public class DemoItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _age;
    private int _score;
    private string _name;

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { if (_age != value) { _age = value; OnPropertyChanged("Age"); } }
    }
    public int Score
    {
        get { return _score; }
        set { if (_score != value) { _score = value; OnPropertyChanged("Score"); } }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { if (_name != value) { _name = value; OnPropertyChanged("Name"); } }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP could implement `protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)` to avoid `OnPropertyChanged("PropertyNameHere")`. With the implementation OP could use `OnPropertyChanged()` without any name specified

Comment: @Nitro.de: that's true, he could, if he used C# 5.0+. He could also use an MVVM framework that has the INPC already implemented in a ViewModelBase class.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your collection changes dramatically every 100 ms, I'd try sending Reset notification from the collection so DataGrid would know that the data needs to be refreshed.
You need to create an ObservableCollection derivative containing method similar to this one

```
public void NotifyOnReset()
{
OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

and invoke it whenever you need.

P.S. Make sure you invoke this method on the UI thread, or employ another syncrhonization approach.

Comment: To those who downvote - have you ever checked performance difference between tens or hundreds of PropertyChanged events, and single Reset notification when collection items changes very frequently? I did. Once case I ended up with throttled Reset as data were changing a way too frequent.