# Gui not updating if property of other class object changed

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to bind some properties (`FooClass.FooString`) of a custom class (`FooClass`) to my `MainWindow`. Now below (**Working known behavior**) is the default working solution if binding some data to a gui.

What I want to do is in the second code block (**Not working, but desired behavior**). Expose some `properties` of another `class`  object`to the gui and update it.
**Problem**: The`TestString`is not getting updated (on the gui, code behind works). The`PropertyChangedevent`is also`null` (not subscribed?!).

*Is this the wrong way how to bind data?*

If I bind the complete `FooClass` `object` to the gui and set `Path` (of `TextBlock`) to `Foo.FooString`, the gui and `string` is updated. But I don't want to do it this way.

*Is this the way how to solve it?*

---

### Working known behavior

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public FooClass Foo { get; } = new FooClass();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += _OnLoaded;
    }

    private async void _OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Foo.ChangeTheProperty();
    }
}

public class FooClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FooString
    {
        get => _FooString;
        set
        {
            if (_FooString == value) return;
            _FooString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _FooString = "empty";

    public void ChangeTheProperty()
    {
        FooString = "Loaded";
    }

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // PropertyChanged
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region PropertyChanged

    /// <summary>
    /// The PropertyChanged Eventhandler
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise/invoke the propertyChanged event!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>        
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Foo.FooString}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

### Not working, but desired behavior

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string TestString => _Foo.FooString;


    private readonly FooClass _Foo;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        _Foo = new FooClass();
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += _OnLoaded;
    }

    private async void _OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _Foo.ChangeTheProperty();
    }
}

public class FooClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string FooString
    {
        get => _FooString;
        set
        {
            if (_FooString == value) return;
            _FooString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private string _FooString = "empty";

    public void ChangeTheProperty()
    {
        FooString = "Loaded";
    }

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // PropertyChanged
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region PropertyChanged

    /// <summary>
    /// The PropertyChanged Eventhandler
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise/invoke the propertyChanged event!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>        
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

#### MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindow}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=TestString}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

#### Solution 1

Subscribe to the `Foo.PropertyChanged` `event` and route it to `MainWindow.PropertyChanged`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public FooClass Foo { get; } = new FooClass();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        Foo.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => OnPropertyChanged(args.PropertyName);
        DataContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += _OnLoaded;
    }

    private async void _OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        Foo.ChangeTheProperty();
    }


    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // PropertyChanged
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    #region PropertyChanged

    /// <summary>
    /// The PropertyChanged Eventhandler
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise/invoke the propertyChanged event!
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: Yes you are correct you need to do the binding through your 'working known behavior' section. That or inside your MainWindow you need to subscribe to the INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged event and then raise the same event from inside your MainWindow class.

Comment: Instead of binding `this` aka `MainWindow` class to `DataContext`, why don't you just bind `Foo` to `DataContext`? Then `TextBlock`'s `Text` can be set to bind to `FooString`. This makes life easier.

Comment: @Bijington Have a look at **Solution 1**. Did you mean that?

@ kurakura88 In my app I have more than one different class object and not only one.

Comment: As a note, implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in the MainWindow is pointless. There is no property where a change notification should be fired.

Comment: @DominicJonas Yes that is what I meant. I wouldn't recommend this approach though as it goes against recommended practises. You should really just stick with your original approach I was just pointing out that this is technically possible.

Answer (score 0):

I might not have fully understood what you want, but here is a working example of data binding, that is somewhat close to your example.

The two main changes were:

1. Set the datacontext to the VM and not the code behind
2. Actually give OnPropertyChanged the argument it needs to correctly trigger the refresh, the name of the property.

**Result:**
[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ListViewColor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Foo.FooString}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Background="Aqua"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
namespace ListViewColor
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public FooClass Foo { get; } = new FooClass();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += _OnLoaded;
        }

        private async void _OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Foo.ChangeTheProperty();
        }
    }
}
```

**FooClass.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class FooClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _FooString = "Empty";
    public string FooString
    {
        get
        {
            return _FooString;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_FooString == value) return;
            _FooString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public void ChangeTheProperty()
    {
        FooString = "Loaded";
    }

    #region PropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
1. Actually it is working with `DataContext = this`. Then u have to define your path like `Path=Foo.FooString`. 
2. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580623/is-callermembername-slow-compared-to-alternatives-when-implementing-inotifypro

Comment: @DominicJonas
Hey, you are right both times! I learned something. But then I don't get the problem, since it works flawless even with those changes!
Do you need something beside the above edited code?