# A monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors, what's the problem?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory, monoids

Who first said the following?

> A monad is just a monoid in the
>   category of endofunctors, what's the
>   problem?

And on a less important note, is this true and if so could you give an explanation (hopefully one that can be understood by someone who doesn't have much Haskell experience)?

Comment: See "Categories for the Working Mathematician"

Comment: You don't need to understand this to use monads in Haskell. From a practical perspective they are just a clever way to pass around "state" through some underground plumbing.

Comment: I'd like to add this excellent blog post here too: http://www.stephendiehl.com/posts/monads.html It doesn't directly answer the question, but in my opinion Stephen does a superb job of tying categories and monads in Haskell together. If you've read the above answers - this should help unify the two ways of looking at this.

Comment: More precisely "For any category C, the category [C,C] of its endofunctors has a monoidal structure induced by the composition. A monoid object in [C,C] is a monad on C." - from en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_%28category_theory%29. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28category_theory%29 for definition of monad in category theory.

Comment: umm I spent over a year now thinking about Haskell and I still can't confidently understand what a functor is(is it a function object? an object you can map over? a function taking a and returning M a? A binary function taking a and returning M a? How can you map over a function if it has no elements to iterate over...) Let alone what an endofunctor is. I understand that fmap lets you apply a function on a boxed object, and >>= lets you push a Boxed object of M into a function a -> M a, but what now?

Comment: @Dmitry A [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) is a function between categories, with some constraints to be well-behaved. An endofunctor on a category C is just a functor from C to itself. [Data.Functor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor) is a typeclass for endofunctors on the [Hask category](http://math.andrej.com/2016/08/06/hask-is-not-a-category/). Since a category consists of objects and morphisms, a functor needs to map both. For an instance f of Data.Functor, the map on objects (haskell types) is f itself and the map on morphisms (haskell functions) is fmap.

Comment: See here for a precise but human explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704652/monad-in-plain-english-for-the-oop-programmer-with-no-fp-background/37345315#37345315

Comment: See Bartosz Milewski's brilliant series of lectures [Category Theory for Programmers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8LbkfSSR58&list=PLbgaMIhjbmEnaH_LTkxLI7FMa2HsnawM_) for the full story. Throughout these Bartosz establish the required prerequisites in Category Theory always linking back to Haskell. The last part is actually called [Monoid in the category of endofunctors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmgoPd7VQ9Q&list=PLbgaMIhjbmEnaH_LTkxLI7FMa2HsnawM_&index=20) and fully answers the question.

Comment: It feels like mathematicians, who invented this term, never though about concepts behind in those terms initially. They thought about a particular problem and gave it a name. Definitions like this rarely reflect ideas behind. I believe a good definition is always preceded with a context and tied terms.

Comment: I can explain it pretty easily like this: https://app.suno.ai/song/dfca38ed-50cb-4f25-939f-90837d6ce92f

Answer (score 966, accepted):

That particular phrasing is by James Iry, from his highly entertaining *[Brief, Incomplete and Mostly Wrong History of Programming Languages](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html)*, in which he fictionally attributes it to Philip Wadler.

The original quote is from Saunders Mac Lane in *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, one of the foundational texts of Category Theory. [Here it is in context](http://books.google.com/books?id=MXboNPdTv7QC&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=%22monoid+in+the+category+of+endofunctors%22+mac+lane&source=bl&ots=feQWTkH2Uw&sig=tv-1JwaMOygKGmFE2vM2FhJVS9o&hl=en&ei=5iWsTJCkBIPSsAPQwJ36Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false), which is probably the best place to learn exactly what it means.

But, I'll take a stab. The original sentence is this:

> All told, a monad in X is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors of X, with product × replaced by composition of endofunctors and unit set by the identity endofunctor.

*X* here is a category. Endofunctors are functors from a category to itself (which is usually *all* `Functor`s as far as functional programmers are concerned, since they're mostly dealing with just one category; the category of types - but I digress). But you could imagine another category which is the category of "endofunctors on *X*". This is a category in which the objects are endofunctors and the morphisms are natural transformations.

And of those endofunctors, some of them might be monads. Which ones are monads? Exactly the ones which are *monoidal* in a particular sense. Instead of spelling out the exact mapping from monads to monoids (since Mac Lane does that far better than I could hope to), I'll just put their respective definitions side by side and let you compare:

### A monoid is...

- A set, ***S***
- An operation, ***• : S × S → S***
- An element of *S*, ***e : 1 → S***

#### ...satisfying these laws:

- *(a • b) • c = a • (b • c)*, for all *a*, *b* and *c* in *S*
- *e • a = a • e = a*, for all *a* in *S*

### A monad is...

- An endofunctor, ***T : X → X*** (in Haskell, a type constructor of kind `* -> *` with a `Functor` instance)
- A natural transformation, ***μ : T × T → T***, where *×* means functor composition (*μ* is known as *[`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join)* in Haskell)
- A natural transformation, ***η : I → T***, where *I* is the identity endofunctor on *X* (*η* is known as *[`return`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:return)* in Haskell)

#### ...satisfying these laws:

- *μ ∘ Tμ = μ ∘ μT*
- *μ ∘ Tη = μ ∘ ηT = 1* (the identity natural transformation)

With a bit of squinting you might be able to see that both of these definitions are instances of the same [abstract concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)).

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation, but I have one question. I get that the monoidal product has type `S × S -> S`, but what is another example of what `×` is, outside of the context of functor composition? For instance, `•` could be multiplication or addition in the natural numbers; what is `×` in this context?

Comment: @Jonathan: In the classical formulation of a monoid, *×* means the cartesian product of sets. You can read more about that here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product, but the basic idea is that an element of *S × T* is a pair *(s, t)*, where *s ∈ S* and *t ∈ T*. So the signature of the monoidal product *• : S × S -> S* in this context simply means a function that takes 2 elements of *S* as input and produces another element of *S* as an output.

Comment: I think the Monoid Maclane is talking about is a little more general than the one you described because the "set" is some object in some category, and the operations are morphism not necessarily defined in terms of elements. And in this particular case it is the category of endofunctors where the product of two objects (where objects are functors) is instead of being the cartesian product it is the composition of the functors... which feels pretty different though I don't have a good intuitive sense of what it means.

Comment: I am confused with your definition of a monoid, specifically: "An element of *S*, **e : 1 -> S**".   So **e** is an element of **S**, but then you define it as "**e : 1 -> S**" which means that **e** is a function with domain **1** and codomain **S**.  What does this mean?

Comment: @TahirHassan - In the generality of category theory, we deal with opaque "objects" instead of sets, and so there is no a priori notion of "elements". But if you think about the category **Set** where the objects are sets and the arrows are functions, the elements of any set S are in one-to-one correspondence with the functions from any one-element set to S. That is, for any element **e** of **S**, there is exactly one function **f : 1 -> S**, where **1** is any one-element set... (cont'd)

Comment: @TahirHassan 1-element sets are themselves specializations of the more general category-theoretic notion of "terminal objects": a terminal object is any object of a category for which there is exactly one arrow from any other object to it (you can check that this is true of 1-element sets in **Set**). In category theory terminal objects are simply referred to as **1**; they are unique up to isomorphism so there is no point distinguishing them. So now we have a purely category-theoretical description of "elements of **S**" for any **S**: they are just the arrows from **1** to **S**!

Comment: @TahirHassan - To put this in Haskell terms, think about the fact that if `S` is a type, all you can do when writing a function `f :: () -> S` is pick out some particular term of type `S` (an "element" of it, if you will) and return it... you've been given no real information with the argument, so there's no way to vary the behavior of the function. So `f` must be a constant function which just returns the same thing every time. `()` ("Unit") is the terminal object of the category **Hask**, and it's no coincidence that there is exactly 1 (non-divergent) value which inhabits it.

Comment: @TahirHassan So while arrows from a terminal object to an object S are not "the same thing" as S's elements, they are *isomorphic* to its elements, which as far as category theory is concerned is just as good.

Comment: So `µ` is join and `η` is return, right? (In the world of Haskell, at least)

Comment: A nice way to say it in one sentence: *Monads are just pipes of (chained) “container” (content) transformations.*  
Read “pipes of (chained)” as “monoidal”, “container” as “category”, and “… transformations” as “functors”, and you have a sentence equivalent to the quoted one.  
**Essentially, monads are (dis)assembly lines. ^^**

Comment: I'm confused, since my (wrong) intuition says that monads are more abstract than monoids (since it deals with endofunctors and transformations which seem more abstract than sets and elements). But from the explanation above (which is obviously correct), monads are a "concretization" of monoids? Obviously I'm not getting this.

Comment: @IvanGozali Set theory is one setting in which you can define what a monoid is; category theory is another, more abstract setting. The set-theoretic definition of monoid falls out as just one special case of the category-theoretic definition (when the category in question is **Set**), and monads are *another* special case (when the category is the category of endofunctors over another category). See the examples given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)#Examples) for more instances of monoids. So monoids really are the more abstract notion.

Comment: The category of endofunctors is said to be a "monoidal category". **Does this make the category of endofunctors *itself* also a monoid?** If so, do monoidal categories always contain monoids as objects? Are monoids always contained in some monoidal category?

Comment: Are all objects in a monoidal category a monoid? Or can some objects be not a monoid?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai To your first question, quoting the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category), "There is a general notion of monoid object in a monoidal category, which generalizes the ordinary notion of monoid. **In particular, a strict monoidal category can be seen as a monoid object in the category of categories Cat (equipped with the monoidal structure induced by the cartesian product).**"

Comment: @CMCDragonkai "A strict monoidal category is one for which the natural isomorphisms α, λ and ρ are identities. Every monoidal category is monoidally equivalent to a strict monoidal category."

Comment: @CMCDragonkai to answer your second question, no, not all objects in a monoidal category are necessarily monoids. For example, **Set** is a monoidal category as we observed above, but take the empty set ∅... it can't be monoidal because there can't be a unit morphism *η : 1 → ∅*. Recall that in the case of **Set**, morphisms are functions and the unit object ("I") is any one-element set.

Comment: @TomCrockett thanks! Just to simplify, monoidal categories are the categorical representation of the classical monoid definition?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai well, the category-theoretic version is a generalization of the idea, which allows us to classify more things as monoids than the set-theoretical definition does. This is because the associativity and identity laws are given in terms of natural isomorphisms instead of simple equalities (they are equalities "up to" natural isomorphism)

Comment: @CMCDragonkai One way to capture the simpler set-theoretic idea of monoid in category theory is by saying it is any monoid object in the monoidal category **Set**, as discussed above...

Comment: @CMCDragonkai another, simpler way is this: a monoid in the set-theoretic sense is a (small) category with only one object. Simply think of the composition of morphisms as the monoid operation, the identity morphism on the single object as the monoid unit, and every other (endo-)morphism as another element of the monoid

Comment: I am also confused at the equivalence between the eta function `η : I → T` and the `return` function in Haskell. Is the `return` function meant to be the eta? I don't quite see the relationship. Is eta is meant to define T as a pointed object?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai Yes, `return` is η. Remember that η is a natural transformation between endofunctors, so it is parameterized by an object (in the case of **Hask**, a type); its signature in Haskell would be something like `η :: I a → T a`. `I` is the identity endofunctor, so we can just write `η :: a → T a`, where `T` is your monadic endofunctor; hopefully that reminds you of the `return` signature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75164/discussion-between-tom-crockett-and-cmcdragonkai).

Comment: I know this answer is old, but it bothers me to find that this popular answer provides the wrong context and wrong definition of monoid. In Mac Lane's book, a monoid may live in any category. And in the said category of endofunctors, there is no squinting required to match his definition of monoid. His monoid in the category of sets would be your (conventional) monoid. Please check the source.

Comment: "And of those endofunctors, some of them might be monads." A monad is not an endofunctor which just _happens_ to satisfy additional properties. A monad is an endofunctor _equipped with_ two natural transformations. This is in the same sense that a group is not a monoid which _happens_ to have inverses for each element, it's a monoid _equipped with_ an additional unary operation which satisfies the inverse law.

Comment: @barron if you really want to be pedantic you could go further and say that a monoid equipped with a unary operation which *just happens* to satisfy the inverse law is not a group either. It must also be *equipped with the proof* that said operation satisfies the inverse law! All a matter of perspective as to which requisites are part of the object language vs the metalanguage.

Comment: @TomCrockett Yes, e.g. the associator/unitor in a monoidal category, but I'm not trying to be quite that pedantic. My point is that the same endofunctor can (in some cases) be made into a monad in different ways, c.f. exotic spheres. To have an endofunctor and say "Is this a monad?" is like having a manifold and asking "Is this a differentiable manifold?" where there may exist several different non-diffeomorphic differential structures on said manifold. The phrasing "Which ones are monads?", to me, suggests that we only care about the existence of the additional data rather than its content.

Comment: Hi, @TomCrockett. You mentioned in comment that "for any element e of S, there is exactly one function f : 1 -> S, where 1 is any one-element set".  Why? I can understand that for any element e of S, there is exactly one function (constant function) mapping from S to {e}, but it seems the f you mentioned is the other way round. IMO, there could be more than one function mapping from {e} to S. Could you please tell me where I am wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @LifuHuang you're right, that was incorrectly worded. What I meant was just the previous sentence: "the elements of any set *S* are in one-to-one correspondence with the functions from any one-element set to *S*", i.e. there is a bijection between *S* and *1 → S*. The obvious bijection takes any given *s ∈ S* to *{(e, s)}*.

Comment: Thanks, @TomCrockett. And one more question, because I have no background in category theory. I am a little bit confused about μ(η(T)) = T = μ(T(η)). My understanding is that η is a morphism(or arrow) pointing from object I to object T (well, of course, in category of endofunctors, a morphism is a natural transformation as you mentioned). Then what does η(T) mean? what puzzles me even more is the meaning of T(η), considered T is an object and η is a morphism. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LifuHuang You can read here for what the notations *ηT* and *Tη* mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Operations_with_natural_transformations ... your question made me realize that my description of the monad laws was incoherent, so I rewrote it. Unfortunately the syntactic similarity to the monoid laws is no longer as obvious; I'll have to think of a way to make that clearer.

Comment: Thanks again, @TomCrockett. I guess the reason why the syntactic similarity now disappear is because you describe associativity and unit of monoid in **Set** in terms of "element a, b, c", while there is no concept of "element" in **End**. But the definition of monoid in terms of "element a, b, c" is the most (and probably the only) acceptable way for newbies (like me). From my perspective, it would be great if you could, after giving the definition of monoid in **Set** in terms of "element a, b, c", also posts the general definition of monoid in monoidal category and then explain(cont'd)

Comment: how the general monoid definition corresponds to the definition of monoid in **Set** and also the one in **End**. Because most people without a background in category theory, I believe, cannot relates the definition here( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory) ) to their familiar definition of monoid in **Set** in terms of elements, not to mention to the definition of monoid in **End**.

Comment: @LifuHuang yep, you've pointed out the exact difficulty! I suspect there are no shortcuts and a satisfying explanation requires introducing the categorical notion of a monoid and showing how that specializes to **Set** and **End** respectively.

Comment: Well, that is indeed not easy. Thank you anyway, this is the best answer regarding monad I have ever read :)

Comment: Oops, one more question. Thanks to your detailed explanation, I have now understood the definition of monad in your post. But when I went back to re-learn the definition  of monad in programming languages. I found the set of laws of monad (https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws) looks different(but alike) from the one in your post. Could you please explain how these two set of laws corresponds to each other? What is the mathematical interpretation of "bind"? Thanks again.

Comment: @LifuHuang The best way to see how this definition relates to Haskell is to note that *μ* is `join` in Haskell, and `m >>= f = join (fmap f m)`. Haskell's monad laws are a restatement of these laws, but in terms of of `>>=`. See this page for more details: https://wiki.haskell.org/Category_theory/Monads.

Comment: Thanks. So $\mu \circ F(\mu)=\mu\circ\mu$ in that page is just the same as $\mu \circ T\mu = \mu \circ \muT$ in your answer, right? $F(\mu)$ looks really weird to me, is it another standard notation?

Comment: @LifuHuang Yes, that's correct. The intuition behind the notation `F(f)` is that a functor *F:* **C → D** is a map between *categories*, and as such maps both objects in **C** (*F(A)*), as well as morphisms in **C** (*F(f)*).

Comment: @LifuHuang In Haskell, where by `Functor` we mean "endofunctor on **Hask**", a `Functor` maps objects of **Hask** to other objects in **Hask**. Since the objects of **Hask** are types, that just means a `Functor` instance `t` can be applied to a type `a` to yield another type `t a`... i.e., it is a type constructor! And the way a `Functor` instance `t` maps a function `f: a -> b` to a function `t a -> t b` is of course via `fmap`.

Comment: @LifuHuang After writing these 2 comments I realized that didn't really answer your question, because what's tricky here is that we're applying *F* not just to a morphism, but to a natural transformation. The intuition wrt Haskell is that natural transformations are polymorphic functions. For example, `id :: forall a. a -> a` is not just a morphism in **Hask** but actually an entire *family* of morphisms--a natural transformation! But `fmap id :: forall a. Functor f => f a -> f a` type checks just fine, and that's exactly what the notation *F(μ)* is about when *μ* is a natural transformation.

Comment: I see. Thanks! I really owe you a hundred upvotes :)

Comment: I think I'm going to read a book on category theory and re-read this comment and answers. I have a feeling some very useful stuff is going over my head ATM.

Comment: Amazing explanation. I am just confused in the last part. Shouldn't it be: `μ ∘ Tη = μ ∘ ηT = μ (the identity natural transformation)` Why does it say 1?

Answer (score 108):

First, the extensions and libraries that we're going to use:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, TypeOperators #-}

import Control.Monad (join)
```

Of these, `RankNTypes` is the only one that's absolutely essential to the below. [I once wrote an explanation of `RankNTypes` that some people seem to have found useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031878/what-is-the-purpose-of-rank2types/12033549#12033549), so I'll refer to that.

Quoting [Tom Crockett's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870310/1477667), we have:

> ### A monad is...
>
> - An endofunctor, ***T : X -> X***
> - A natural transformation, ***μ : T × T -> T***, where *×* means functor composition
> - A natural transformation, ***η : I -> T***, where *I* is the identity endofunctor on *X*
>
> #### ...satisfying these laws:
>
> - *μ(μ(T × T) × T)) = μ(T × μ(T × T))*
> - *μ(η(T)) = T = μ(T(η))*

How do we translate this to Haskell code? Well, let's start with the notion of a **natural transformation**:

```
-- | A natural transformations between two 'Functor' instances.  Law:
--
-- > fmap f . eta g == eta g . fmap f
--
-- Neat fact: the type system actually guarantees this law.
--
newtype f :-> g =
    Natural { eta :: forall x. f x -> g x }
```

A type of the form `f :-> g` is analogous to a function type, but instead of thinking of it as a *function* between two *types* (of kind `*`), think of it as a **morphism** between two **functors** (each of kind `* -> *`). Examples:

```
listToMaybe :: [] :-> Maybe
listToMaybe = Natural go
    where go [] = Nothing
          go (x:_) = Just x

maybeToList :: Maybe :-> []
maybeToList = Natural go
    where go Nothing = []
          go (Just x) = [x]

reverse' :: [] :-> []
reverse' = Natural reverse
```

Basically, in Haskell, natural transformations are functions from some type `f x` to another type `g x` such that the `x` type variable is "inaccessible" to the caller. So for example, `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` cannot be made into a natural transformation, because it's "picky" about which types we may instantiate for `a`. One intuitive way I often use to think of this is the following:

- A functor is a way of operating on the *content* of something without touching the *structure*.
- A natural transformation is a way of operating on the *structure* of something without touching or looking at the *content*.

Now, with that out of the way, let's tackle the clauses of the definition.

The first clause is "an endofunctor, ***T : X -> X***." Well, every `Functor` in Haskell is an endofunctor in what people call "the Hask category," whose objects are Haskell types (of kind `*`) and whose morphisms are Haskell functions. This sounds like a complicated statement, but it's actually a very trivial one. All it means is that that a `Functor f :: * -> *` gives you the means of constructing a type `f a :: *`  for any `a :: *` and a function `fmap f :: f a -> f b` out of any `f :: a -> b`, and that these obey the functor laws.

Second clause: the `Identity` functor in Haskell (which comes with the Platform, so you can just import it) is defined this way:

```
newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }

instance Functor Identity where
    fmap f (Identity a) = Identity (f a)
```

So the natural transformation ***η : I -> T*** from Tom Crockett's definition can be written this way for any `Monad` instance `t`:

```
return' :: Monad t => Identity :-> t
return' = Natural (return . runIdentity)
```

Third clause: The composition of two functors in Haskell can be defined this way (which also comes with the Platform):

```
newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }

-- | The composition of two 'Functor's is also a 'Functor'.
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose fga) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) fga)
```

So the natural transformation ***μ : T × T -> T*** from Tom Crockett's definition can be written like this:

```
join' :: Monad t => Compose t t :-> t
join' = Natural (join . getCompose)
```

The statement that this is a monoid in the category of endofunctors then means that `Compose` (partially applied to just its first two parameters) is associative, and that `Identity` is its identity element. I.e., that the following isomorphisms hold:

- `Compose f (Compose g h) ~= Compose (Compose f g) h`
- `Compose f Identity ~= f`
- `Compose Identity g ~= g`

These are very easy to prove because `Compose` and `Identity` are both defined as `newtype`, and the Haskell Reports define the semantics of `newtype` as an isomorphism between the type being defined and the type of the argument to the `newtype`'s data constructor. So for example, let's prove `Compose f Identity ~= f`:

```
Compose f Identity a
    ~= f (Identity a)                 -- newtype Compose f g a = Compose (f (g a))
    ~= f a                            -- newtype Identity a = Identity a
Q.E.D.
```

Comment: In the `Natural` newtype, I can't figure out what the `(Functor f, Functor g)` constraint is doing. Could you explain?

Comment: @dfeuer It's not really doing anything essential.

Comment: @LuisCasillas I've removed those `Functor` constraints since they don't seem necessary. If you disagree then feel free to add them back.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what it means formally for the product of functors to be taken as composition?  In particular, what are the projection morphisms for functor composition?  My guess is that the product is only defined for a functor F against itself, F x F and only when `join` is defined.  And that `join` is the projection morphism.  But I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think the three isomorphisms listed at the end are quite the same as saying "monoid in the category of endofunctors". In particular they don't mention `join'` and `return'` at all.

Comment: you should probably start your answer with "haskell"

Answer (score 29):

The answers here do an excellent job in defining both monoids and monads, however, they still don't seem to answer the question:

> And on a less important note, is this true and if so could you give an explanation (hopefully one that can be understood by someone who doesn't have much Haskell experience)?

The crux of the matter that is missing here, is the different notion of "monoid", the so-called *categorification* more precisely  -- the one of monoid in a monoidal category. Sadly Mac Lane's book itself [makes it very confusing](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=MXboNPdTv7QC&pg=PA138&lpg=PA138&dq=%22monoid%20in%20the%20category%20of%20endofunctors%22%20mac%20lane&source=bl&ots=feQWTkH2Uw&sig=tv-1JwaMOygKGmFE2vM2FhJVS9o&hl=en&ei=5iWsTJCkBIPSsAPQwJ36Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> All told, a monad in `X` is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors of `X`, with product `×` replaced by composition of endofunctors and unit set by the identity endofunctor.

### Main confusion

Why is this confusing? Because it does not define what is "monoid in the category of endofunctors" of `X`. Instead, this sentence suggests taking a monoid inside **the set of all endofunctors** together with the functor composition as binary operation and the identity functor as a monoidal unit. Which works perfectly fine and turns into a monoid any subset of endofunctors that contains the identity functor and is closed under functor composition.

Yet this is not the correct interpretation, which the book fails to make clear at that stage. A Monad `f` is a *fixed* endofunctor, not a subset of endofunctors closed under composition. A common construction is to use `f` to *generate* a monoid by taking the set of all `k`-fold compositions `f^k = f(f(...))` of `f` with itself, including `k=0` that corresponds to the identity `f^0 = id`. And now the set `S` of all these powers for all `k>=0` is indeed a monoid "with product × replaced by composition of endofunctors and unit set by the identity endofunctor".

And yet:

- This monoid `S` can be defined for any functor `f` or even literally for any self-map of `X`. It is the monoid generated by `f`.
- The monoidal structure of `S` given by the functor composition and the identity functor has nothing do with `f` being or not being a monad.

And to make things more confusing, the definition of "monoid in monoidal category" comes later in the book as you can see from the [table of contents](https://books.google.co.th/books?id=6KPSBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=contents%20mac%20lane%20Categories%20for%20the%20Working%20Mathematician&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKg_emjYrkAhVFinAKHVqHCuYQ6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=contents%20mac%20lane%20Categories%20for%20the%20Working%20Mathematician&f=false). And yet understanding this notion is absolutely critical to understanding the connection with monads.

### (Strict) monoidal categories

Going to Chapter VII on Monoids (which comes later than Chapter VI on Monads), we find the definition of the so-called **strict monoidal category** as triple `(B, *, e)`, where `B` is a category, `*: B x B-> B` a *bifunctor* (functor with respect to each component with other component fixed) and `e` is a unit object in `B`, satisfying the associativity and unit laws:

```
(a * b) * c = a * (b * c)
a * e = e * a = a
```

for any objects `a,b,c` of `B`, and the same identities for any morphisms `a,b,c` with `e` replaced by `id_e`, the identity morphism of `e`. It is now instructive to observe that in our case of interest, where `B` is the category of endofunctors of `X` with natural transformations as morphisms, `*` the functor composition and `e` the identity functor, all these laws are satisfied, as can be directly verified.

What comes after in the book is the definition of the "relaxed" *monoidal category*, where the laws only hold modulo some fixed natural transformations satisfying so-called *coherence relations*, which is however not important for our cases of the endofunctor categories.

### Monoids in monoidal categories

Finally, in section 3 "Monoids" of Chapter VII, the actual definition is given:

> A monoid `c` in a monoidal category `(B, *, e)` is an object of `B` with two arrows (morphisms)

```
mu: c * c -> c
nu: e -> c
```

making 3 diagrams commutative. Recall that in our case, these are morphisms in the category of endofunctors, which are natural transformations corresponding to precisely `join` and `return` for a monad. The connection becomes even clearer when we make the composition `*` more explicit, replacing `c * c` by `c^2`, where `c` is our monad.

Finally, notice that the 3 commutative diagrams (in the definition of a monoid in monoidal category) are written for general (non-strict) monoidal categories, while in our case all natural transformations arising as part of the monoidal category are actually identities. That will make the diagrams exactly the same as the ones in the definition of a monad, making the correspondence complete.

### Conclusion

In summary, any monad is by definition an endofunctor, hence an object in the category of endofunctors, where the monadic `join` and `return` operators satisfy the definition of *a monoid in that particular (strict) monoidal category*. Vice versa, any monoid in the monoidal category of endofunctors is by definition a triple `(c, mu, nu)` consisting of an object and two arrows, e.g. natural transformations in our case, satisfying the same laws as a monad.

Finally, note the key difference between the (classical) monoids and the more general monoids in monoidal categories. The two arrows `mu` and `nu` above are not anymore a binary operation and a unit in a set. Instead, you have one fixed endofunctor `c`. The functor composition `*` and the identity functor alone do not provide the complete structure needed for the monad, despite that confusing remark in the book.

Another approach would be to compare with the standard monoid `C` of all self-maps of a set `A`, where the binary operation is the composition, that can be seen to map the standard cartesian product `C x C` into `C`. Passing to the categorified monoid, we are replacing the cartesian product `x` with the functor composition `*`, and the binary operation gets replaced with the natural transformation `mu` from 
`c * c` to `c`, that is a collection of the `join` operators

```
join: c(c(T))->c(T)
```

for every object `T` (type in programming). And the identity elements in classical monoids, which can be identified with images of maps from a fixed one-point-set, get replaced with the collection of the `return` operators

```
return: T->c(T)
```

But now there are no more cartesian products, so no pairs of elements and thus no binary operations.

Comment: So what is your answer to the "is this true" part of the question?  Is it true that a monad is a monoid in the category of endofunctors?  And if yes, what is the relationship between the category theory notion of a monoid and an algebraic monoid (a set with an associative multiplication and a unit)?

Comment: @AlexanderBelopolsky, technically, a monad is a monoid in the monoidal category of endofunctors equipped with functor composition as its product.  In contrast, classical "algebraic monoids" are monoids in the monoidal category of sets equipped with the cartesian product as its product.  So, both are specific cases of the same general categorical definition of monoid.

Comment: @AlexanderBelopolsky I have tried to explain that the answer is "yes", but with the more technical categorical notion of a monoid, when taken in the category of endofunctors of a fixed category. The easier more familiar "algebraic monoid" is a (categorical) monoid taken in the category of sets. As K.A.Buhr is saying above, you can see them as different special cases of the same general construction.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it accurately describes what Saunderas and Mac Lane meant.

Answer (score 9):

I came to this post by way of better understanding the inference of the infamous quote from Mac Lane's *Category Theory For the Working Mathematician*.

In describing what something is, it's often equally useful to describe what it's not.

The fact that Mac Lane uses the description to describe a Monad, one might imply that it describes something unique to monads. Bear with me. To develop a broader understanding of the statement, I believe it needs to be made clear that he is *not* describing something that is unique to monads; the statement equally describes Applicative and Arrows among others. For the same reason we can have two monoids on Int (Sum and Product), we can have several monoids on X in the category of endofunctors. But there is even more to the similarities.

Both Monad and Applicative meet the criteria:

- endo => any arrow, or morphism that starts and ends in the same place
- functor => any arrow, or morphism between two Categories

  (e.g., in day to day `Tree a -> List b`, but in Category `Tree -> List`)
- monoid => single object; i.e., a single type, but in this context, only in regards to the external layer; so, we can't have `Tree -> List`, only `List -> List`.

The statement uses "Category of..." This defines the scope of the statement. As an example, the Functor Category describes the scope of `f * -> g *`, i.e., `Any functor -> Any functor`, e.g., `Tree * -> List *` or `Tree * -> Tree *`.

What a Categorical statement does not specify describes where *anything and everything is permitted*.

In this case, inside the functors, `* -> *` aka `a -> b` is not specified which means `Anything -> Anything including Anything else`. As my imagination jumps to Int -> String, it also includes `Integer -> Maybe Int`, or even `Maybe Double -> Either String Int` where `a :: Maybe Double; b :: Either String Int`.

So the statement comes together as follows:

- functor scope  `:: f a -> g b` (i.e., any parameterized type to any parameterized type)
- endo + functor `:: f a -> f b` (i.e., any one parameterized type to the same parameterized type) ... said differently,
- a monoid in the category of endofunctor

So, where is the power of this construct? To appreciate the full dynamics, I needed to see that the typical drawings of a monoid (single object with what looks like an identity arrow, `:: single object -> single object`), fails to illustrate that I'm permitted to use an arrow parameterized with *any number* of monoid values, from the *one* type object permitted in Monoid. The endo, ~ identity arrow definition of equivalence *ignores* the functor's *type value* and both the type and value of the most inner, "payload" layer. Thus, equivalence returns `true` in any situation where the functorial types match (e.g., `Nothing -> Just * -> Nothing` is equivalent to `Just * -> Just * -> Just *` because they are both `Maybe -> Maybe -> Maybe`).

Sidebar: ~ outside is conceptual, but is the left most symbol in `f a`. It also describes what "Haskell" reads-in first (big picture); so Type is "outside" in relation to a Type Value. The relationship between layers (a chain of references) in programming is not easy to relate in Category. The Category of Set is used to describe Types (Int, Strings, Maybe Int etc.) which includes the Category of Functor (parameterized Types). The reference chain: Functor Type, Functor values (elements of that Functor's set, e.g., Nothing, Just), and in turn, everything else each functor value points to. In Category the relationship is described differently, e.g., `return :: a -> m a` is considered a natural transformation from one Functor to another Functor, different from anything mentioned thus far.

Back to the main thread, all in all, for any defined tensor product and a neutral value, the statement ends up describing an amazingly powerful computational construct born from its paradoxical structure:

- on the outside it appears as a single object (e.g., `:: List`); static
- but inside, permits a lot of dynamics

  - any number of values of the same type (e.g., Empty | ~NonEmpty) as fodder to functions of any arity. The tensor product will reduce any number of inputs to a single value... for the external layer (~`fold` that says nothing about the payload)
  - infinite range of *both* the type and values for the inner most layer

In Haskell, clarifying the applicability of the statement is important. The power and versatility of this construct, has absolutely nothing to do with a monad per se. In other words, the construct does not rely on what makes a monad unique.

When trying to figure out whether to build code with a shared context to support computations that depend on each other, versus computations that can be run in parallel, this infamous statement, with as much as it describes, is not a contrast between the choice of Applicative, Arrows and Monads, but rather is a description of how much they are the same. For the decision at hand, the statement is moot.

This is often misunderstood. The statement goes on to describe `join :: m (m a) -> m a` as the tensor product for the monoidal endofunctor. However, it does not articulate how, in the context of this statement, `(<*>)` could also have also been chosen. It truly is an example of 'six in one, half a dozen in the other'. The logic for combining values are exactly alike; same input generates the same output from each (unlike the Sum and Product monoids for Int because they generate different results when combining Ints).

So, to recap: A monoid in the category of endofunctors describes:

```
 ~t :: m * -> m * -> m *
 and a neutral value for m *
```

`(<*>)` and `(>>=)` both provide simultaneous access to the two `m` values in order to compute the the single return value. The logic used to compute the return value is exactly the same. If it were not for the different shapes of the functions they parameterize (`f :: a -> b` versus `k :: a -> m b`) and the position of the parameter with the same return type of the computation (i.e., `a -> b -> b` versus `b -> a -> b` for each respectively), I suspect we could have parameterized the monoidal logic, the tensor product, for reuse in both definitions. As an exercise to make the point, try and implement `~t`, and you end up with `(<*>)` and `(>>=)` depending on how you decide to define it `forall a b`.

If my last point is at minimum conceptually true, it then explains the precise, and only computational difference between Applicative and Monad: the functions they parameterize. In other words, the difference is *external* to the implementation of these type classes.

In conclusion, in my own experience, Mac Lane's infamous quote provided a great "goto" meme, a guidepost for me to reference while navigating my way through Category to better understand the idioms used in Haskell. It succeeds at capturing the scope of a powerful computing capacity made wonderfully accessible in Haskell.

However, there is irony in how I first misunderstood the statement's applicability outside of the monad, and what I hope conveyed here. Everything that it describes turns out to be what is similar between Applicative and Monads (and Arrows among others). What it doesn't say is precisely the small but useful distinction between them.

Comment: @TylerH Thank you for the edits.  I'm glad it remains a useful read.  My only FYI is that there is a convention to use italics when using Latin terminology.  Examples include "per se", "in vivo", "in vitro", "et. al.". I suspect that strictly speaking "e.g.", "etc." and "i.e." likely also qualify?..

Comment: Only when they are not part of the common vernacular/adopted into English. Once they've reached that point, they don't need italics. See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364903/does-the-phrase-per-se-have-to-be-italicized Per is itself extremely common (and never italicized), and I would argue per se is common enough. But if you think it should remain italicized, I won't fight you on it further.

Comment: I agree per se is often used. If there is a convention on stackexchange, you did the right thing.

Answer (score 7):

*Note:* No, this isn't true. At some point there was a comment on this answer from Dan Piponi himself saying that the cause and effect here was exactly the opposite, that he wrote his article in response to James Iry's quip. But it seems to have been removed, perhaps by some compulsive tidier.

Below is my original answer.

---

It's quite possible that Iry had read [From Monoids to Monads](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/11/from-monoids-to-monads.html), a post in which Dan Piponi (sigfpe) derives monads from monoids in Haskell, with much discussion of category theory and explicit mention of "the category of endofunctors on [Hask](https://wiki.haskell.org/Hask)" . In any case, anyone who wonders what it means for a monad to be a monoid in the category of endofunctors might benefit from reading this derivation.