# Monads as Monoids in practice

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to understand the relationship between monads and monoids in more practical ways. I apologize in advance if this question makes no sense, I'm still struggling.

Suppose for example, I have:

```
trait Monoid[T] {
  def zero: T
  def combine: (T,T) => T
}
```

and (from [here](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/ruby/monads-are-not-metaphors)):

```
trait Monad[+M[_]] {
  def unit[A](a: A): M[A]
  def bind[A, B](m: M[A])(f: A => M[B]): M[B]
}
```

Is there a relationship that can be established between Monad and Monoid traits, such as that I can treat a Monad as a Monoid (assuming I understand correctly that a Monad is a special case of a Monoid)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [monoid vs monad in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745994/monoid-vs-monad-in-scala)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The linked answer is more theoretical, my question is more code-oriented. But the linked accepted answer says 'they are nothing like each other' (no relationship in practice) so if that's the proper answer code-wise, I will accept it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will probably see the connection more easily if you write a monad using `unit` and `join` instead of `unit` and `bind`:

```
trait Monoid[T] {
  def zero: T
  def combine: (T,T) => T
}

trait Monad[M[_]] {
  def unit[A]: A => M[A]
  def join[A]: M[M[A]] => M[A]
}
```

Join is Scala's `flatten`, and bind is Scala's `flatMap`.

Note that in order to define a monad just by using `unit` and `flatten/join`, you must also provide the method `map[A](m: M[A])(f: A => B): M[B]`. This comes from the fact that monad is actually an (endo)functor with two natural transformations, unit and join. Since it's a functor, it has the `map` functionality. Depending on your code design, `map` should be either defined together with `unit` and `join` inside your Monad trait or inherited from some Functor trait that would be extended by your Monad trait.

For completeness, let me state all three possible ways of defining a monad:

- unit + flatMap
- unit + flatten + map
- unit + compose

All three can be expressed using one of the other two. I will skip the code to demonstrate this since it's not directly related to the question, but I can add it in edit if needed.

Comment: `join` has type `M[M[A]] => M[A]`.

Comment: Bah, right. Fixed. I was thinking of the M x M → M notation for the natural transformation.

Comment: Thanks, I also appreciate that you listed the three possible ways to define a monad, I didn't see it so succinctly put in my other readings.