# Derivation of Free Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

`Control.Monad.Free` implements a free monad as:

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Free (f (Free f a))

instance Functor f => Functor (Free f) where
  fmap f = go where
    go (Pure a)  = Pure (f a)
    go (Free fa) = Free (go <$> fa)
```

I am having a lot of trouble understanding the second `go` line, especially in the context of descriptions of [what a free monad is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352205/what-are-free-monads). Can somenoe please describe how this works and why it makes `Free f a` a free monad?

Comment: `<$> == fmap`, maybe that makes it more clear. This is more or less the only possible implementation.

Comment: @NiklasB. can `<$>` be used both prefix and infix?

Comment: @groovy: Yeah, just like any function: `(+1) <$> [1,2,3] == (<$>) (+1) [1,2,3] == fmap (+1) [1,2,3] == (+1) \`fmap\` [1,2,3]`

Answer (score 14):

At this point, you're just making `Free` a functor rather than a monad. Of course, to be a monad, it has to be a functor as well!

I think it would be a little easier to think about if we rename the `Free` constructor to avoid confusion:

```
data Free f a = Pure a | Wrap (f (Free f a))
```

Now let's look at the structure of what we're building up. For the `Pure` case, we just have a value of type `a`. For the `Wrap` case, we have *another* `Free f a` value wrapped in the `f` functor.

Let's ignore the constructors for a second. That is, if we have `Wrap (f (Pure a))` let's think of it as `f a`. This means that the structure we're building up is just `f`--a functor--applied repeatedly some number of times. Values of this type will look something like: `f (f (f (f (f a))))`. To make it more concrete, let `f` be `[]` to get: `[[[[[a]]]]]`. We can have as many levels of this as we want by using the `Wrap` constructor repeatedly; everything ends when we use `Pure`.

Putting the constructors back in, `[[a]]` would look like: `Wrap [Wrap [Pure a]]`.

So all we're doing is taking the `Pure` value and repeatedly applying a functor to it.

Given this structure of a repeatedly applied functor, how would we map a function over it? For the `Pure` case--before we've wrapped it in `f`--this is pretty trivial: we just apply the function. But if we've already wrapped our value in `f` at least once, we have to map over the outer level and then recursively map over all the inner layers. Put another way, we have to map mapping over the `Free` monad over the functor `f`.

This is exactly what the second case of `go` is doing. `go` itself is just `fmap` for `Free f a`. `<$>` is `fmap` for `f`. So what we do is `fmap` `go` over `f`, which makes the whole thing recursive.

Since this mapping function is recursive, it can deal with an arbitrary number of levels. So we can map a function over `[[a]]` or `[[[[a]]]]` or whatever. This is why we need to `fmap go` when go is `fmap` itself--the important difference being that the first `fmap` works for a *single* layer of `f` and `go` recursively works for the *whole* `Free f a` construction.

I hope this cleared things up a bit.

Answer (score 7):

To tell you the truth, I usually just find it easier *not* to read the code in these simpler functions, but rather to read the *types* and then write the function myself.  Think of it as a puzzle.  You're trying to construct this:

```
mapFree :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> Free f a -> Free f b
```

So how do we do it?  Well, let's take the `Pure` constructor first:

```
mapFree f (Pure a) = ...
-- I like to write comments like these while using Haskell, then usually delete 
-- them by the end:
--
-- f :: a -> b
-- a :: a
```

With the two type comments in there, and knowing the type of `Pure`, you should see the solution right away:

```
mapFree f (Pure a) = Pure (f a)
```

Now the second case:

```
mapFree f (Free fa) = ...
-- f  :: a -> b
-- fa :: Functor f => f (Free f a)
```

Well, since `f` is a `Functor`, we can actually use `mapFree` to apply `mapFree f` to the inner component of `f (Free f a)`.  So we get:

```
mapFree f (Free fa) = Free (fmap (mapFree f) fa)
```

Now, using this definition as the `Functor f => Functor (Free f)` instance, we get:

```
instance Functor f => Functor (Free f) where
  fmap f (Pure a) = Pure (f a)
  fmap f (Free fa) = Free (fmap (fmap f) fa)
```

With a bit of work, you can verify that the definition we just arrived at here is the same thing as the one you're puzzling over.  (As others have mentioned, `(<$>)` (defined in `Control.Applicative`) is just a synonym for `fmap`.)  You may still not understand it, but you managed to write it, which for types as abstract as these is very often good enough.

As for understanding it, though, the thing that helps me is the following: think of a `Free` monad as a sort of list-like structure, with `Pure` as `[]` and `Free` as `(:)`.  From the definition of the type you should see this: `Pure` is the base case, and `Free` is the recursive case.  What the `fmap` instance is doing is "pushing" the mapped function to the bottom of this structure, to where the `Pure` lives.

Answer (score 1):

Since I am confused myself, I answer with a question...could this be a correct substitution (relying on Tikhon's Wrap clarification)?

```
...
fmap g = go where
  go (Pure a)  = Pure (g a)
  go (Wrap fa) = Wrap (go <$> fa)

Substituting "fmap g" for "go", and "fmap" for "<$>" (since "<$>" is infix, 
 we flip "go" and "<$>"):

fmap g (Pure a)  = Pure (g a)
fmap g (Wrap fa) = Wrap (fmap (fmap g) fa)

Substituting "f (Free f a)" for "fa" in the last line (from the first data 
 declaration):

fmap g (Wrap fa) = Wrap ( fmap (fmap g) (f (Free f a)) )

                 = Wrap ( f ( fmap g (Free f a) ) )

                 = wrap ( f (Pure (g a) ) ) --if Free f a is Pure
                 or
                 = Wrap ( f ( fmap g (Wrap fa') ) ) --if Free f a is Wrap

The last line includes the recursion "fmap g (Wrap fa')", which would continue 
 unless Pure is encountered.
```

Comment: A free monad is `0` or more `Wrap`s terminating in a `Pure`.  `fmap f` applies the `f` function to the value stored in the final `Pure`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez thanks, that's a very concise and clear explanation. Can I ask you if the substitution I wrote makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, except for one typo.  It should be `wrap (f (Pure (g a)))` instead of `wrap (f (Pure g a))`.  Other than that you have it correct.

Comment: Hi groovy, how did you get from `Wrap ( fmap (fmap g) (f (Free f a)) )` to `Wrap ( f ( fmap g (Free f a) ) )` ?

Comment: Hi groovy, how did you get from `Wrap ( fmap (fmap g) (f (Free f a)) )` to `Wrap ( f ( fmap g (Free f a) ) )` ?

Comment: @me2 think of the type of fmap -- given a function `(a -> b)` and a functor `f a`, fmap applies the function to `a`, resulting in `f b`. A step before `f b` could be written as `f ( (a -> b) a )`. Since inside the Wrap, we have an expression that looks like `fmap (some function) (f a)`, we can move the function inside the functor to get `Wrap ( f ( (fmap g) a ) )`. Our `a` in this case is `(Free f a)` and the function is `(fmap g)`. Because of the nature of fmap, we can remove those inner parentheses to get `Wrap ( f ( fmap g a ) )`, where `a` is `(Free f a)`. Does that make sense?