# Implementing Applicative (<*>) for StateT

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, applicative

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18673525/is-it-possible-to-implement-applicative-m-applicative-statet-s-m), but without a real answer. In fact the accepted answer suggests that it is not possible, despite the fact that

- StateT is a Monad, and hence a superset of Applicative. As a result, the standard libraries simply use `(<*>) = ap`
- (as Petr notes) composing applicatives always yields an applicative.

One of the implementations of MaybeT I've read about used

```
liftA2 (<*>) :: (Applicative f, Applicative f1) => f (f1 (a -> b)) -> f (f1 a) -> f (f1 b)
```

to implement Applicative but I can't make that work here. My work in progress has tried lots of options around the following:

```
-- (<*>) :: StateT s f (a -> b) -> State s f a -> State s f b
instance (Applicative f) => Applicative (StateT s f) where
    pure a =  StateT $ \s -> pure (a, s)
    (StateT f) <*> (StateT g) = StateT $ \s ->          -- f :: s -> m (a -> b, s),  g :: s -> m (a, s)
                                    let
                                        mabs = f s          -- mabs :: m (a -> b, s)
                                        mab = fmap fst mabs
                                        ms' = fmap snd mabs

                                    in undefined
```

I'm wondering what I am missing, and hoping that I will learn something about Applicative in the process.

Comment: Stacking transformers is not quite the same as composing functors. Hence "composing applicatives always yields an applicative" doesn't really help.

Comment: ...if you're ok with `(Monad f) => `, then the task is of course simple: just inline the definition of `>>=` into the definition of `ap`, and simplify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementation (taken from [Tony Morris' functional programming course](https://github.com/NICTA/course)) could be

```
(<*>) :: (Functor f, Monad f) =>
  StateT s f (a -> b)
  -> StateT s f a
  -> StateT s f b
StateT f <*> StateT a =
  StateT (\s -> (\(g, t) -> (\(z, u) -> (g z, u)) <$> a t) =<< f s)
```

Comment: That uses a monadic bind.

Comment: That's OK, because f is a Monad by defintion of a Transformer. I just need to de-minify the rest...

Answer (score 4):

Tony uses some alternative notation, and Simon's answer is very terse, so here is what I ended up with:

```
-- (<*>) :: StateT s f (a -> b) -> State s f a -> State s f b
instance (Monad f, Applicative f) => Applicative (StateT s f) where
    pure a =  StateT $ \s -> pure (a, s)
    StateT f <*> StateT a =
        StateT $ \s -> 
                f s >>= \(g, t) ->                   -- (f s) :: m (a->b, s)
                    let mapper = \(z, u) -> (g z, u) -- :: (a, s) -> (b, s)
                    in fmap mapper (a t)             -- (a t) :: m (a, s)
```

I had to declare f also a Monad, but that is OK as it is part of the definition of a Monad transformer, as I understand it.