# Why is this Applicative instance for StateT working?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, state, monads, applicative

I am a Haskell (and CS) beginner. I am working my way through the [haskellbook](https://haskellbook.com). I was implementing the `Applicative` instance for `StateT` where `StateT` is defined as :

`newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runState :: s -> m (a, s) }`

It is mentioned in the book that for creating an `Applicative` instance for `StateT s m` we need a `Monad` constraint on `m` rather than an `Applicative` constraint as one would expect. I had also reached the same conclusion on reading the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18673914/11728033) for the SO answer referenced in the book.
But, I tried to create an `Applicative` instance with an `Applicative` constraint on `m` for better understanding, and it successfully compiled. I also tried it on a few examples and it seems to work fine. Can someone please explain, what's wrong here?

```
instance (Applicative m) => Applicative (StateT s m) where
  pure a = StateT $ \s -> pure $ (a, s)
  (<*>) :: (StateT s m (a -> b)) -> (StateT s m a) -> (StateT s m b)
  (StateT smf) <*> (StateT sma) = StateT $ \s -> (f) <$> (smf s) <*> (sma s)
                                  where
                                    f :: (a -> b, s) -> (a, s) -> (b, s)
                                    f (ff, s) = \(a, s) -> (ff a,s)
```

```
*StateT> s1 = StateT (\s -> return (4, s))
*StateT> s2 = map (+) s1
*StateT> s3 = StateT (\s -> return (20, s))
*StateT> runState (s2 <*> s3) * 10
(24,10)
*StateT>
```

**EDIT** : As @Koterpillar advised me to try this with examples where state is also modified. I tried with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCJDG.jpg) example. Also, [here](https://pastebin.com/ssFbCnRv) is the `Monad` constraint version, which I think also doesn't behave as it should. I think the problem is with states not being linked together somehow. If someone can shed some light on this topic, I would be grateful.

Comment: Please try this with `smf` and `sma` that modify state.

Comment: Please remove the png and replace with formatted text.

Comment: @Michael Litchard Is it okay now? Sorry, I should I have posted the text initially.

Comment: Looking good. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `<*>` for `StateT` should do:

1. Run `smf` with the initial state
2. Run `sma` with the state from `smf`
3. Return this final state

This is what your code does:

1. Run `smf` with the initial state
2. Run `sma` with **the initial state**
3. Return this final state

In other words, the bug is that **the state changes caused by `smf` are discarded**.

We can demonstrate this issue with code that modifies the state in `smf`. For example:

```
s1 = StateT $ \s -> return (const (), s + 1)
s2 = StateT $ \s -> return ((), s)
```

Then `runState (s1 <*> s2) 0` will return `((), 1)` with the standard implementation, but `((), 0)` with your one.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand now. That's the mistake I am doing in the `Monad` constraint version too. I have to feed initial state `s` to `smf` and then the state returned from `smf` to `sma`. I thought of combining the two states but they are not `Semigroup`.

Comment: This kind of threading of states reminds of `bind` somehow. Maybe that's why we need a Monad.

Comment: If you `<>` the states instead, then you get a `Writer` monad -- and indeed that has a `Monoid` constraint. (It needs `Monoid`, not just `Semigroup`, to provide an empty state for `return`.)

Comment: Oh, I don't know about `Writer` monads yet, but thanks a lot.