# What does Pure mean in Free monad in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, free-monad

I try to learn free monads. I found following:

```
data Free f r = Free (f (Free f r)) | Pure r
```

What does Pure mean? And why do I need r with Pure?

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352205/what-are-free-monads already?

Comment: `Pure` is the name of a constructor. You need `r` in `Pure r` because you need to put something inside of `Pure`. You can't put `f` inside of `Pure` because there are no values of type `f`. So you have a second type variables, and that's what you put inside `Pure`. If the questions is why you need `Pure` at all, the answer is you need a way to end your recursive structure (why do you need `[]`?). The constructor which is the leaf node can be in the `Free` datatype, or it can be in the `f` which is inside `Free`, in which case you would have 2 distinct (redundant) leaf node constructors.

Answer (score 2):

`Pure` corresponds to the `return` operation -- conceptually it attaches to your functor the ability to "inject" a value. The `Free` constructor corresponds to "join".

If you want to understand why you "need" `Pure`, try to remove it and give the `Monad` instance and see where you get stuck!