# >>= implementation for Poor Man's Concurrency Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

Hi I am trying to implement the Poor Man's Concurrency Monad.
Here is my code:

```
import Control.Monad

data Concurrent a = Concurrent ((a -> Action) -> Action)

data Action 
    = Atom (IO Action)
    | Fork Action Action
    | Stop

instance Monad Concurrent where
    (Concurrent ma) >>= f = Concurrent (\x -> ma(\y -> "Something return a Action")) 
    return x = Concurrent (\c -> c x)
```

Here is my analysis:
`x` has the type of `b`, `y` has the type of `a`, `f` has the type of `(a -> ((b ->Action) -> Action))`. In order to figure out "Something return a Action", I firstly calculate `(f y)`, which returns a type of `((b ->Action) -> Action)`. Then, how can use it with `x` to generate a Action?

Comment: Your analysis is wrong. `x` has type `b -> Action`, not `b`.

Comment: You might want to check out the [Free Monad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352205/what-are-free-monads). It allows you to record a monad, which can be arbitrarily replayed. I used it for lightweight threads.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The definition you are looking for reads something like

```
Concurrent h >>= k  =  Concurrent (\f -> h (\x -> runConcurrent (k x) f))
```

How did we get there? As always, we let the types do the work. :)

Let us first introduce a helper function:

```
runConcurrent                 :: Concurrent b -> (b -> Action) -> Action
runConcurrent (Concurrent h)  =  h
```

If you start out with the left-hand side of your definition

```
Concurrent h >>= k  =  ...
```

with `h :: (a -> Action) -> Action` and `k :: a -> Concurrent b`, then your goal is to replace `...` with an expression of type `Concurrent b`, isn't it?

How can we construct a value of type `Concurrent b`? One way is to apply our function `k`, but that won't work, because we don't have a suitable value of type `a` available as an argument. So, pretty much the only thing we can do is to apply the data constructor `Concurrent` which is of type `((b -> Action) -> Action) -> Concurrent b`.

That gives:

```
Concurrent h >>= k = Concurrent ...
```

Now we have to go and find us an expression of type `(b -> Action) -> Action` to supply as an argument for `Concurrent`. We know that expressions of function type can always be constructed through lambda-abstraction:

```
Concurrent h >>= k  =  Concurrent (\f -> ...)
```

This gives us `f :: b -> Action` and the obligation to replace `...` with an expresion of type `Action`. Using one of the `Action`-constructors directly would be cheating of course ;). To guarantee the genericity of `(>>=)` (more precisely, to make sure that we end up obeying the monad laws), we treat `Action` as if it's an abstract datatype. Then, the only way to produce an `Action`-value is to apply the function `h`:

```
Concurrent h >>= k  =  Concurrent (\f -> h ...)
```

Hence, next we need to supply `h` with an argument of type `a -> Action`. That is a function type again, so we throw in another lambda:

```
Concurrent h >>= k  =  Concurrent (\f -> h (\x -> ...))
```

Hence, we have `x :: a` and need to construct a body of type `Action`. What can we do with a value of type `a`? We can supply it to the function `k`. This gives us a value of type `Concurrent b`, which we can then pass to our helper function `runConcurrent`:

```
Concurrent h >>= k  =  Concurrent (\f -> h (\x -> runConcurrent (k x) ...))
```

This gives us a function of type `(b -> Action) -> Action` and supplying `f` as an argument does the trick:

```
Concurrent h >>= k  =  Concurrent (\f -> h (\x -> runConcurrent (k x) f))
```

Comment: Little mistake type of the data constructor `Concurrent` is `((b -> Action) -> Action) -> Concurrent b` not `((b -> Action) -> b) -> Concurrent b`. Am I right ?

Comment: @fdelsert You're absolutely right. Thanks for spotting it. Corrected it in the answer.