# Why this free monad example is failing?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, free-monad

I'm trying to understand how Free monads work in Haskell, and for that I've been trying to make an example work. My code was based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352205/what-are-free-monads) by Philip JF. Here is the example:

```hs
data Free f a = Pure a | Roll (f (Free f a))
--it needs to be a functor
instance Functor f => Functor (Free f) where
  fmap f (Pure a) = Pure (f a)
  fmap f (Roll x) = Roll (fmap (fmap f) x)

--this is the same thing as (++) basically
concatFree :: Functor f => Free f (Free f a) -> Free f a
concatFree (Pure x) = x
concatFree (Roll y) = Roll (fmap concatFree y)

data F a = One a | Two a a | Two' a a | Three Int a a a
  deriving Show

-- Lift F into the Free monad
type FreeF a = Free F a

tree :: FreeF String
tree = Roll (One (Pure "A"))

example1 :: F (FreeF String)
example1 = One (Roll (One (Pure "A")))
```

The code above works. What I then wanted to do was to come up with a `FreeF (f (FreeF a))` in order to apply the `concatFree` function to it. Here is where I get into trouble.

```hs
result :: FreeF (FreeF String)
result = Roll (One (Roll (One (Pure "A"))))
```

The code above does not work. For me, it would seem that this construction was correct. What am I missing?

To be more precise, when I try to run this with ghci, I get the error:

```
FreeMonads3.hs:25:10: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Free F String’
      Expected type: FreeF (FreeF String)
        Actual type: Free F [Char]
    • In the expression: Roll (One (Roll (One (Pure "A"))))
      In an equation for ‘result’:
          result = Roll (One (Roll (One (Pure "A"))))
   |
25 | result = Roll (One (Roll (One (Pure "A"))))
```

Comment: If you wanted a double nesting of `FreeF` wouldn't you need 2 `Pure` in your stack? As it is your function quite obviously (to me) is only a `FreeF String` which is just another name for the type the compiler expects `Free F [Char]` or put differently nesting in`Roll` doesn't add layers of `Free` only `Pure` does that.

Comment: To obtain a `FreeF (FreeF String)`, you need to start from `Pure x` where `x :: FreeF String`. You only have one `Pure` and that wraps a `String`. You need at least one other `Pure`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very proficient in Haskell. Can you give an actual example?

Comment: As mentioned by n.m, you need to insert yet one more `Pure` constructor to raise your expression to the 2nd level of  `Free F`. Note that in that case the expression includes 2 versions of Pure, Roll,... of different types. Like this: `result = Roll (One ( **Pure** (Roll (One (Pure "A")))))`

Comment: Also please note that you can avoid heavy parenthesis nesting by using '$' as the low precedence function call operator. Like this: `result = Roll $ One $ Pure $ Roll $ One $ Pure "A"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your expression:

```
result :: FreeF (FreeF String)
result = Roll (One (Roll (One (Pure "A"))))
```

all instances of the `Roll` and `One` constructors operate internally within the first level `FreeF` type.

As mentioned in the comments, it takes a second `Pure` operator to get into the `FreeF (FreeF String)` type.
Like this:

```
result :: FreeF (FreeF String)
result = Roll (One ( Pure (Roll (One (Pure "A")))))
```

**Side note 1**:

It is possible to avoid the heavy parenthesis nesting above by leveraging the `.` function composition operator and the `$` low precedence function call operators provided by Haskell.

Like this:

```
result1 :: FreeF (FreeF String)
result1 = Roll $ One $ Pure $ Roll $ One $ Pure "A"
```

or like that:

```
result2 :: FreeF (FreeF String)
result2 = Roll . One . Pure . Roll . One . Pure  $  "A"
```

Note that above, the two instances of the `Roll` constructor have different types. Same for the `One` and `Pure` constructors.
For example the type of the leftmost `Pure` constructor is:
`FreeF String -> FreeF (FreeF String)`

**Side note 2**:

To have a proper free monad, you need to ensure that there is a `Functor` instance for your `F` type constructor. The cheapest way to ensure this is:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  DeriveFunctor  #-}

data F a = One a | Two a a | Two' a a | Three Int a a a
  deriving (Show, Functor)
```

However, as a beginner it might be worthwhile to write the relevant code for `fmap` manually, as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `result` as you defined it is actually:

```
result :: FreeF String
result = Roll (One (Roll (One (Pure "A"))))
```

That's because the type of `Roll` (specialized to `FreeF`) is `F (FreeF a) -> FreeF a`.

To get the desired type, use `Pure` instead of `Roll`. `Pure` has type `a -> FreeF a`

```
result :: FreeF (FreeF String)
result = Pure (One (Roll (One (Pure "A"))))
```