# Associative binary operation for Option in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, monoids

I remember that `monad` is a `monoid`. That is, there is an *associative binary operation* `*` so that if `ma` and `mb` are *monadic values* then `ma * mb` is a monadic value too.

If the above is correct, what is that binary operation for `Option` in Scala ?  For example, what can be `*` in `Some(1) * Some(2)` ?

Comment: What do you mean on `ma` and `mb`? For instance `Option(1)` and `Option(2)`?

Comment: Why? Isn't `append` a binary associative operation? What is `Some(z)` append {`Some(x)` append `Some(y)`}? Is that the same if you change order?

Comment: @senia Yes (updated the question), I mean something like `Some(1) * Some(2)`. What is `*` here ?

Comment: The question is: Do you really want to know…? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3870310/200266 (Answer: `*` == `join`/`flatten`; **1** == `return`.)

Comment: @Debilski Could you please elaborate a bit and maybe give a full answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*This answer stole its definitions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870310/200266 and only tries to give a rough explanation. My knowledge of category theory is rather basic.*)

In the generic case, saying that a monad is also a monoid is only valid, if you consider the functor (eg. `T => Option[T]`) and not the values (eg. `Some(3)` or `None`).

As an example for a monoid over values, let’s have a look at `List[T]`.

We have a binary operation **• : S × S -> S**:

```
def append[T](list1: List[T], list2: List[T]): List[T] = list1 append list2
```

and the empty list `Nil` is obviously the identity element. There is no `append` method in every monad, though, so the above cannot be generalised onto all monads. Let’s change the definition of the binary operation a bit.

Now, in the above case **×** can be seen as returning a tuple of the input values:

```
List[T] × List[T] => (List[T], List[T])
```

And our `append` function receives this tuple as its input.

However, we may change the tupling operation **×** to **∘**, now meaning functor composition.

```
(K => List[K]) ∘ (K => List[K]) => (K => List[List[K]])
```

And so, we’re looking for a function fulfilling **μ : T ∘ T -> T** or more specific

```
(K => List[List[K]]) => (K => List[K])
```

That operation is known in Scala as `flatten` (`join` in Haskell). The monoid’s identity element is the the monad constructor which has no generic name in Scala (`return` in Haskell), but which exists for every monad. Eg. `x => List(x)`.

To wrap things up, considering this and the other answers in this question, there are three possibilities for how a monad can be a monoid:

A) Every monad is also a monoid in the above sense under functor composition.

B) Every monad `M[T]` has a monoid if there is also a monoid (with some binary operation `~+~`) for T: `for {x <- ma; y <- mb} yield x ~+~ y`

C) *Some* monads may have one or more specific monoids which differs from the one in B. For example `List`’s append or `Option`’s `orElse`.

Answer (score 4):

I think `orElse` is a valid associative binary operator:

```
def test(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int], c: Option[Int]): Boolean =
  ((a orElse b) orElse c) == (a orElse (b orElse c))

Seq(Option(1), Option(2), None).permutations.forall {
  case Seq(a, b, c) => test(a, b, c)
}
```

This holds. I have used this property in a FingerTree implementation, it was proposed by Hinze & Paterson in their Haskell version, it is used to implement an interval tree.

Comment: Thanks. And what is the _identity_ for this operation ?

Comment: @Michael: `None orElse b` == `b orElse None` == `b`.

Comment: @Michael: The identity element in this would be `None`. `None orElse Some(3) == Some(3) == Some(3) orElse None`. This is no answer however to the question how *every* monad is also a monoid.

Answer (score 3):

An `Option` by itself is not a monoid just like an `Integer` is not a monoid by itself. A monoid is a type AND the associative binary operation.

You can consider the Integer type AND addition a monoid. Integer and multiplication are a monoid too. Turning two `Integer`s to `String` and concatenating them ("2" + "3" = "23") is a valid associative operation too that could create a monoid with Integers: in fact `("2" concat "3") concat "4"` = `"2" concat ("3" concat "4"`) = "234".

The thing is, it's up to you to define the associative operation that completes the definition of "monoid" for a type, so your question "what is THE associative operation...." is not well-formed.

As with Integers, `Option[Int]` and addition or multiplications can be monoids, but an `Option[Int]` per se is not.

Like @senia does in his answer you can say "I can define a monoid based on Option[T] if T is itself a Monoid". In that case, the associative operation can use the one that was defined for T and `Some[a] append Some[b]` can be `Some[a append b]`.

Or, as @0__ did, you can find a particular operation (`orElse`) that, together with `Option[Int]` makes a monoid. That is correct too (but notice how the answer starts with "orElse is **a** valid associative binary operator").

Answer (score 2):

Actually not. `Monad` for `Option` is not a `Monoid` for `Option[T]`. `Monad` is defined for `M[_]` and `Monoid` is defined for `T`.

You can create `Monoid` for `Option[T]` if you have `Monoid` for `T` like this:

```
def optionMonoid[T: Monoid]: Monoid[Option[T]] = new Monoid {
  def zero: Option[T] = None
  def append(f1: Option[T], f2: => Option[T]): Option[T] = (fi, f2) match {
    case (None, None) => None
    case (Some(a), Some(b)) => Some(a |+| b)
    case (r @ Some(_), None) => r
    case (None, r @ Some(_)) => r
  }
}
```

Comment: "`Monad` is not a `Monoid`". [Well, actually...](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2009/05/brief-incomplete-and-mostly-wrong.html)

Comment: @TravisBrown: I've tried to express this in `scala` as `def monadIsMonoid[...: Monad]: Monoid[...]` and it looks like it's impossible. Is there a programming language where one can express this idea in code?

Comment: Wrong monoid; see my answer.

Comment: @senia: Sorry, meant mostly as a joke, but you can do it if you have [kind polymorphism](http://www.jonmsterling.com/posts/2012-01-12-unifying-monoids-and-monads-with-polymorphic-kinds.html).

Answer (score 2):

There are two different senses of monoid. A monad is a [monoid object in the category theory sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_%28category_theory%29) (see the last example there); it isn't a [monoid in the abstract algebra sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) (which most other answers are talking about).