# Access variables in Gatling feeder with gRPC

Tags: scala, grpc, gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to create my gRPC payload by reading data from a csv file(it has guestID and category as columns). 
I followed the example here https://github.com/phiSgr/gatling-grpc/blob/244ab372da6773102d79c65a7e4086f409d3fe94/src/test/scala/com/github/phisgr/example/GrpcExample.scala but I see a type mismatch error when I try the same. (it expects Seq[ContextKey] but here i am able to form Seq[Expression[ContextKey]])

```
val scn2: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("gRPC call - 50 users repeated 100 times")
  .feed(csv("testtext.csv"))
  .exec(
    grpc("gRPC request with test message")
      .rpc(RecommenderGrpc.METHOD_GET_RECOMMENDATIONS)
      .payload(RequestContext.of(Map("test" -> "test"),
        Seq(ContextKey.defaultInstance.updateExpr(
          _.id :~ $("guestID"),
          _.`type` :~ Type.GUEST
        ), ContextKey.defaultInstance.updateExpr(
          _.id :~ $("category"),
          _.`type` :~ Type.CATEGORY
        )),
        Seq())
      )
  )
```

(payload is a RequestContext object which takes in metadata, keys and items. metadata is a map, keys is a Seq of ContextKey and items is empty Seq. ContextKey contains string guestID or category and type).

How to use the variables in the feeder here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip to the bottom for the solution.

---

`Expression[T]` is an alias for `Session => Validation[T]`. In plain English, that is a function that constructs the payload from the session with a possibility of failure.

You can consider an `Expression[T]`, abstractly, "contains" a `T`.

---

Like how a `Promise` in JavaScript "contains" a future value. You cannot give a `Promise` of `T` to a function that expects a `T`. If one wants to transform or combine `Promise`s, that code has to be turned inside out, and supplied as an argument to `.then`.<sup>1</sup>

```js
aPromise + 1 // wrong
aPromise.then(a => a + 1)
```

This is the same reason why your code sample does not compile.

---

Users of Gatling are not necessarily familiar with Scala, or functional programming in general. It will be counterproductive to make them understand this "wrapping" stuff.<sup>2</sup> So there are code that help you combine the `Expression`s.

For HTTP and other untyped stuff, the [EL string](https://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/) is parsed and transformed in to an `Expression` under the hood.

Protobuf messages are strongly typed, the payload cannot be easily constructed using string interpolation. So the `:~` operators on lenses are used to handle the plumbing so that you do not have to manually handle the `Expression` wrapping.

---

But now you have a function, `RequestContext.of`, that constructs the payload. The lens magic cannot help if you need that function. You have to write the `Expression` lambda yourself.<sup>3</sup>

```scala
.payload { session =>
  for {
    guestId <- session("guestId").validate[String]
    category <- session("category").validate[String]
  } yield RequestContext.of(
    Map("test" -> "test"),
    Seq(
      ContextKey(id = guestID, `type` = Type.GUEST),
      ContextKey(id = category, `type` = Type.CATEGORY)
    ),
    Seq()
  )
}
```

---

0. Needless to say this is very cumbersome, and people now use async-await with `Promise`s.
1. An `Expression` is just the `Either` monad and the `Reader` monad stacked together, [what's the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870088/a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-problem)?
2. I may be able to write a version with lenses if I know what `RequestContext.of` does.

Comment: Thank you, George. This worked for me

` val scn2: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("gRPC call - multiple requests using feeder")
    .feed(csv("get_recs_data.csv").circular)
    .exec(
      grpc("gRPC request with test message")
        .rpc(RecommenderGrpc.METHOD_GET_RECOMMENDATIONS)
        .payload(session => RequestContext.of(metadata = Map("test" -> "test"),
          keys = Seq(ContextKey.of(session("guestID").as[String],Type.GUEST),
            ContextKey.of(session("category").as[String],Type.CATEGORY)), items = Seq())
        )
    )`

Comment: This had zero upvotes when I came across it, which is criminal because this is not covered in the gatling grpc docs and I had been struggling all day to find the solution :)

Comment: Well, sorry for the lack of documentation. :( But in my defence I do not expect a person having a code base with custom Scala functions to create payloads would need a tutorial for manipulating "wrapped" objects.