# How are Haskell Monad laws derived from Monoid laws?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory, monoids

The laws for monoids in the category of endofunctors are:

[image: monoid laws]

And the Haskell monad laws are:

Left identity: `return a >>= k = k a`

Right identity: `m >>= return = m`

Associativity: `m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h) = (m >>= k) >>= h`

I'm assuming the latter is derived from the former, but how so? The diagrams basically say

```
join (join x) = join (fmap join x)
join (return x) = x
join (fmap return x) = x
```

How are these equivalent to the Haskell monad laws?

Comment: See also [A monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors, what's the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870088/a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-problem). Doesn't really answer your question, but there's some good reading there anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the `>>=`-monad laws from the `join`-monad laws,  one needs to define `x >>= y` in terms of multiplication (`join`), unity (`return`), and functoriality (`fmap`), so we need to let, by definition,

```
(x >>= y) = join (fmap y x)
```

## Left identity law

The left identity law then becomes

```
return a >>= k = k a
```

By definition of `>>=`, it is equivalent to

```
join (fmap k (return a)) = k a
```

Now, `return` is a natural transformation `I -> T` (where `I` is the identity functor), so `fmap_T k . return = return . fmap_I k = return . k`. We reduce the law to:

```
join (return (k a)) = k a
```

And this follows by the `join` laws.

## Right identity law

The right identity law

```
m >>= return = m
```

reduces to, by definition of `>>=`:

```
join (fmap return m) = m
```

which is exactly one of the `join` laws.

I'll leave the associativity law for you to prove. It should follow using the same tools (`join` laws, naturality, functoriality).

Answer (score 2):

Phrase the monad laws in terms of [the Kleisli composition operator `(>=>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-).

Assuming `k :: a -> m b`, `k' :: b -> m c`, `k'' :: c -> m d` (i.e. `k`, `k'`, `k''` are Kleisli arrows)

- Left identity: `return >=> k = k`
- Right identity: `k >=> return = k`
- Associativity: `(k >=> k') >=> k'' = k >=> (k' >=> k'')`

It's relatively straightforward from the definition of `(>=>)` to show that these are equivalent to what you wrote. And you don't need any fancy diagrams or anything: these are *literally* the monoid laws, with `return` as the identity and `(>=>)` as your monoid operation.

The diagram you show in your picture is a different way of thinking about monads. You can equivalently define monads in terms of natural transformations (i.e. `join` and `return`) or in terms of composition (i.e. `return` and `(>>=)` / `(>=>)`). The latter approach lends itself to the monoid way of thinking that you're looking for.

Comment: Your last paragraph says that the diagram is a different way of thinking about monads. But the question *starts* with that assumption and asks how the two different ways of thinking are connected. This answer doesn't appear to talk about that at all.

Comment: those are _literally_ the _category_ laws, not the monoid laws. Kleisli arrows form a [category](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html#t:Category), not a monoid. an arrow `Kleisli m a b` goes from `a` to `b`. those are two different objects in the Kleisli category. a monoid viewed as a category [has only one object](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332690/monoid-as-a-single-object-category). In Haskell, `Monoid t`, like `Monoid (Sum Int)`. `(<>) :: a -> a -> a` but `Category.. :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c`.

Comment: i.e. `(<=<) :: Kleisli m b c -> Kleisli m a b -> Kleisli m a c`. so a `Monad m` induces a category `Monad m => Category (Kleisli m)`.

Comment: @WillNess : A monoid can alternatively be defined as an object in a monoidal category. The category of endofunctors has monoidal structure with functor composition as multiplication and the identity functor as unit.

Comment: @BartoszMilewski of course. I was reacting to the answer that presents the Kleisli category as this monoid.