# In depth understanding of Monad

Tags: c++, monads, category-theory, monoids

At one time, I thought I understood Monad. However, when I try to connect my understanding of code to the piece of theory, I found myself still not clear. So here it is:

**part 1.** Here is the popular educational SO link [a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870088/a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-problem).

My questions:

1. The highest scored answer says monad is a monoid. And the monoid is consisted of a set S, an operation * and e. The it explains what monad is right after the monoid definition. The first thing that I want to confirm is that the element of the set S is the endofunctor T:X->X mentioned in Monad definition, correct?
2. The question title quotes the famous phrase saying "a monoid in the category of endofunctors". Here, I am a bit confused by "category of endofunctors". A category as we know consisted of objects and morphisms. So here is it correct to say endofunctors are the objects and the operation * mentioned in the previous question is the morphism? I don't quite understand what does the "**in**" (a monoid **in** the category...) mean in mathematics. Does it mean "belongs to", "is" or "include"?

**part 2.** Here is another link [No, really, what's a monad?](https://rmarcus.info/blog/2016/12/14/monads.html), which I initially found very instructive. However recently I found I could not clearly map the code in its example to the formal definition. My experience with Haskell is limited, so I focus on its c++ sample code. Here is the one the author claims it's a monad.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string ret(string x) {
  return "[" + x + "]";
}

string bind(string x, string (*func) (string)) {
  return "[" + func(x.substr(1, x.length() - 2)) + "]";
}

string step1(string x) {
  return "Hello " + x;
}

string step2(string x) {
  return x + ", monads aren't that complicated."; 
}

string step3(string x) {
  return "***" + x + "***";
}

template<typename T> T run(T (*ret) (string), 
                           T (*bind) (T, string (*) (string))) {
  
  T x = "friend";
  
  // first, wrap up the value of x
  x = ret(x);
  
  // now use wrapCall to run each step
  x = bind(x, step1);
  x = bind(x, step2);
  x = bind(x, step3);
  return x;
}

int main() {
    cout << run<string>(ret, bind) << "\n";
}
```

Then the author says:

> Believe it or not, we’ve just written a monad (specifically, the monad is the pair of bind and ret)!

My questions:

3. Is the function `string ret(string x)` here corresponding to the e in monoid definition? But the e should apply to the set S elements.
4. In this code, which function is the T (the element of the set S)? It's supposed to be a functor. I guess `step1, step2, step3` are. However, they don't look like functors but categories. Since they just act like arrows linking objects (type string to type string). A functor should link two categories.
5. Is `bind` the operation * (natural transformation μ : T × T → T)?

Hopefully I state my confusion well, any help is appreciate.

Comment: Aside: I don't like the final example, because it assumes that `T` is `string`. It should really start `T x = ret("friend");`

Answer (score 1):

I think I've figured it out. Let me answer this question by myself. In the C++ code that I posted, the `[]` is the type constructor, `bind` function corresponding to the `fmap` in Haskell, hence they two form a functor, which is the `T` mentioned here [a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870088/a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-problem).

The `ret` function is the natural transformation, η. The `run` actually represent the natural transformation, μ.

Comment: You're correct, what the author calls `bind` is `fmap` and what he calls a monad is a functor (with `return` it's actually a pointed functor, but still not a monad).